# Using multiple Git repositories in a single Team Foundation Server project

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've started using Team Foundation Service 2012 (The cloud based offering) now that they have announced support for using Git as a source control solution.

My initial test was a single projected with a single Git repository named after the project.

Everything went well, I could clone the repo, commit push and pull from within Visual Studio 2012 and more importantly the work item association worked as well.

For the real project however, it made more sense to split the codebase across multiple Git repos in the TFS project.

There was no obstruction in doing this, the interface for Team Foundation Service supported it quite nicely....

BUT

Now I find that in Visual Studio 2012 there are a few issues and I wonder if I've either done something wrong, or if its just something that is not fully supported (yet?)

- After testing, I've found that if the Git repo does not have the same name as the project then you lose the ability to clone the repo easily. The default URL that comes up always assumes the Git repo is named after the projected.
- Likewise, when the repo does not have the same name, you completely lose the ability to associate work items with commits. It also displays "(Local)" after the Git repo name, as if it has no idea that its actually associated with the TFS Project at all.

Anyone else find this and perhaps a solution (while still allowing multiple Git repos under the same TFS Project) ?

UPDATE:
Found a few links such as these two

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3811952-allow-multiple-git-repositories-in-a-single-team-p

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/dff9c737-fbd1-4ca8-9c32-3be14eb614ba/what-is-the-best-team-project-setup-for-using-git-with-tfs

So at least one other person has bumped into it.

The multiple repo's work fine if you use Git to push remotely to the correct repo URL, it only breaks down if you use the Visual Studio 2012 integration in terms of work item association and cloning the repo.

Comment: What do you mean "clone easily"?  Are you actually having trouble cloning repos?

Comment: yes, if the repo has a different name to the project, when you hit clone inside visual studio it fails because the target URL defaults to the name of the project. You can work around this by manually editing the URL to target the desired repo inside the project. This will get the clone working, but all linkage to work items etc.. is still lost.

Comment: I see what you're saying now, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Thats ok. I love that MS has embraced Git for us DVCS followers, but the whole point of Git is using multiple repos to seperate logical areas/projects etc.. If they could get this working it would be the icing on the cake

Comment: Definitely.  The Visual Studio Tools for Git (the extension you're using for Visual Studio 2012) is still in preview.  These limitations should be fixed in Visual Studio 2013.  We're trying to move quickly here on both Team Foundation Service and the Visual Studio integration; that means that sometimes it's tough to coordinate schedules.  Apologies for the inconveniences.

Comment: @EdwardThomson No need to apologise ! I'm loving VS2012 and I think it's fantastic what MS is doing. For a small developer like myself, being able to use TFS online is even more icing on an already excellent cake.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of the [Visual Studio Tools for Git](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c) extension that is available for Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

This problem does not exist in the Git tools that come as part of [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs).

Comment: I'm using the VS2013 (last update) and I am facing the same problem!

Comment: I am not sure what you could be facing as 2013 support multiple git repos on the same Team Project easily.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you Connect>ManageConnections> 
that you click on the repo (under the project) rather than just the project.

For a project with just one repo in, VS works it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue in VS 2017.
Under my connect menu I noticed it was listing the Team Project and the old repo (with the same name) under it. Obviously this was not correct as we have renamed the old repo and added more.

What fixed it was going into the manage connections modal and reconnecting from there, this forced the UI to load the correct repo names under the Team project in the team explorer which I COULD then connect to and checkin code with work items. I think the team explorer window loves to cache references and never update them unless you force it to.
[image]